# How to assign bean value to JLabel in Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, javabeans, jlabel

I am trying to design GUI in Eclipse Juno,for that i create a Bean called NameBean,and try to fetch that label_name through getName() method, i am trying to do:

GUI Class:

```
    String label_name = NameBean.getName();
    JLabel lblName = new JLabel();
    lblName .setText(label_name);
    lblName .setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblName .setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
    getContentPane().add(lblName , "cell 3 0");
```

My Main class:

```
 List<NameBean> nameBean= new ArrayList<NameBean>();
     nameBean.setName("StackOverFlow");
     Constant_GUI.map_Settings.put("Element_Statictext_value", nameBean);
     nameBeanList.add(receiptReport_GUI_DTO);
```

It prints <**dynamic**> in design instead of actual value,but when i pass text directly to label_name then it prints correct value.

for example:

```
String label_name = "StackOverflow";
```

It prints **StackOverflow** in design view,If anyone have answer of how to pass bean value to JLabel then please tell me.

Regards.

Comment: I presume your IDE can't predict what will be the value returned by `NameBean.getLabel()` at runtime, and thus displays "<dynamic>" instead.

Comment: after assigning the bean value to label_name i print it,then it prints  correctly means value successfully assign to label_name but not assign to jLabel.

Comment: That means that you're assigning a value to label_name after the JLabel has been created. To change the text of the JLabel, your code must call lblName.setText(). I really advise you to learn basic Java principles, and to code your GUI by hand, instead of using a GUI builder without understanding how it works.

Comment: @JBNizet first i assign NameBean.getLabel() value to label_name and then create jLabel.And i also tried lblName.setText(label_name); but i gives same problem to me.please help

Comment: Post a short, but complete program. I can't debug code without seeing it.

Comment: i post code for jLabel above,please check this.